# Accessing POST-data in a Java-Agent

Tags: java, ajax, lotus-notes

The task is quite simple. I have an agent on my database, written in Java and I have a website, from where I want to send an ajax-call to my database. So far, I have only figured out, how to access GET-data sent from a client.

Now my question: How do you access POST-data in a lotus-notes agent written in Java?

(following the very basic java code I use in my agent to make it accessible from the web)

```
import lotus.domino.*;

public class ExampleAgent1 extends AgentBase {

    public void NotesMain(){
        try{
            Session session = getSession();
            AgentContext context = session.getAgentContext();

            /*
                insert logic here (obviously the statement to retrieve POST-data)
            */

        }
        catch(Exception exc){
            System.out.println("Unknown error occured");
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a DocumentContext property on the agent context object. On that document, there will be an item called "Request_Content" that will contain your post data.

```
import lotus.domino.*;

public class ExampleAgent1 extends AgentBase {

    public void NotesMain(){
        try{
            Session session = getSession();
            AgentContext context = session.getAgentContext();
            Document doc = agentContext.getDocumentContext();
            System.out.println(doc.getItemValueString("Request_Content"));
        }
        catch(Exception exc){
            System.out.println("Unknown error occured");
        }
    }

}
```